# Replace placeholders with text - C?

Tags: c, replace

I use the below function to retrieve characters one by one from a FILE stream.
Now the text in that file will sometimes include places holders like !first_name! within the text. What's the best way to detect when such a place holder start and when it ends so that I can swap each character between !! with proper character from another storage?

```
void print_chars(FILE *file) {
        fseek(file, 0L, 0);
        int cr;

        do {
              cr = fgetc(file);
              putchar(cr);
        } while (cr != EOF);
}
```

Comment: The "best" way is to use a language that is designed for text processing (\<cough\>Perl\<cough\>) but barring that _where are you stuck_? What ideas do you have thus far? What have you tried? I don't know about everyone but I'm not going to just hand you some code.

Comment: @Chris Lutz, if you don't feel like answering why bother commenting?  He wasn't asking this question to you specifically and people below have already provided him with some solid advice.  Also, suggesting using another language is far from helpful.

Comment: @KingNestor: I think Chris has some valid points. If it's not necessary for goe to do this in C, he might consider another language. And it doesn't hurt to let people know what you've already tried.

Comment: People don't usually post entire projects here, usually just changing the language is something far from feasible when you already have 3000 lines committed.. plus C is faster in almost all cases

Comment: @KingNestor - I was working on something and was going to post an answer, and then @Jonathan beat me to the answer I would have posted, so I upvoted him rather than post a duplicate answer, which you can clearly see if you had read that far. @earlz - I doubt it. Perl's regex engine is highly optimized, much more highly optimized than the average C version. I would suspect that the speed difference, if any, is going to be insignificant for all but the most extreme cases (billions and billions of entries). If you want, I can whip up a couple benchmarks, but don't knock Perl's regex engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also take a more primitive approach also by reading it in 1 character at a time and then breaking out if char=='!' and then build a string up til the other '!' and then just compare that string with your list of replacements..

@goe's reply
To say push a char.. here is some code

```
//c is char read from file
if(c=='!'){
  char str[100];
  c=fgetc
  int i=0;
  while(c!='!'){
    str[i]=c;
    i++;
    c=fgetc
  }
  i++;
  str[i]='\0'; //null terminate
  if(strcmp(str,"....")... //continue... 
}
```

Comment: That's what I think I'll do. Could you tell me how I can push if you will a single char into a char some_string[100]; ? Is there a good function that would allow me to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Start by using `fgets()` to read lines at a time, and then (assuming placeholders won't have spaces or newlines in them), use `strchr()` to locate the first exclamation mark, another to find the second, and `strcpsn()` or `strspn()` to ensure that only permitted characters appear between them.  Then write what goes before the first exclamation mark and the replacement text, and then resume scanning for more placeholders on the same line.

Comment: I was going to write this answer up eventually. And then I didn't. +1 I would have tried to work within his char-at-a-time framework, but this is probably easier.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a finite automaton aka state machine?

Comment: This is a good answer too.  Reminds me of my Compiler homework using finite automata.

Comment: I would say its a bit overkill though for something simple like this

Answer (score 1):

If you want something reliable that handles corner cases, consider using a real lexical analysis tool like Lex or re2c.