# Replacing a word in a file, using C

Tags: c, replace

How do I replace a word in a file with another word using `C`?

For example, I have a file which contains:

```
my friend name is sajid
```

I want to replace the word *friend* with *grandfather*, such that the file is changed to:

```
my grandfather name is sajid
```

(I am developing on Ubuntu Linux.)

#### Update:

I am doing filing in C. I have created a .txt file and write some data into it, but as my program progresses I have to search some text and replace it with the other words.  The problem I am facing is that suppose in my file I wrote

```
"I bought apple from the market"
```

If i replace apple with pineapples as apple has 5 char and pineapple has 9 char it will write it as

```
"I bought pineapple m the market"
```

It also has affected the words written after apple.

I have to do it using C, not a command line script.

Comment: please show the code you're using that's not working.

Comment: You have to learn how to ask questions first. I bet that if you rephrase, and clearly state your problem, you will find a solution yourself. See http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Im a bit confused at what your asking? Or what language/program your using? Since most text editors have a Replace Function?

Comment: Similar questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672581/string-replace-in-file-using-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733058/replace-placeholders-with-text-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211749/c-file-programming-replace-a-text-in-a-file-using-posix-calls

Comment: Hi mainajaved, have you solved the problem? I have the same problem as you. It will be nice if you could share the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the exiting Linux sed program?

`sed -i 's/friend/grandfather/' filename`

That will replace friend with grandfather in the existing file.  Make a copy first if you want to keep the original!

Edit:

Alternatively, load the file into an STL string, replace 'friend' with 'grandfather' using a technique such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494399/how-do-i-search-find-and-replace-in-an-stl-string), and save the new string into a file.

Comment: He did mention that he wanted to do it in `C`.

Comment: I know, but using sed would save him having to code anything. It isn't clear if sajid _has_ to write the code, or is writing the code just to do search/replace on the file.

Comment: It sounds like a task which one would do to learn `C` (or perhaps homework?). Using `sed` wouldn't be of much benefit if that's the case.

Comment: True.  Would spawning sed from C be classed as cheating? ;)

Comment: I believe it would be! Nice try... :)

Answer (score 1):

As you've realized, you won't be able to make the change in place in the original file.

The easy solution is to read each string from the original file and write it to standard output, making the replacement as necessary.  In pseudocode:

```
open original file
while not at end of original file
  get next string from original file
  if string == "friend"
    write "grandfather" to standard output
  else
    write string to standard output
end while
```

You can then redirect the output to another file when you execute it, similar to how `sed` and `awk` work.

Alternately, you can create a destination file in the code and write to it directly.  If you need to replace the original file with the new file, you can use the `remove()` and `rename()` library functions in `stdio`.

Comment: thanks so much John Bode got your point but also i have one other problem that continously updating and every line of file has differnt word to replace with  i you want i will explain you my program