# filing in c language

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacing a word in a file, using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042196/replacing-a-word-in-a-file-using-c)

i am doing filing in c language. i have created a txt file and write some data into it. but as my program progress i have to search some text and replace it with the other word but the problem i am facing is that suppose in my file i wrote

"i bought apple from the market"

if i replace apple with pineapples , as apple has 5 char and pineapple has 9 char it will write it as

"i bought pineapple m the market"

that it also has affect the words written after apple because of the different char length

i have use fseekpos function to find the pointer position

thanks

Comment: Everything's correct. What's the question then?

Comment: sounds like an assignment from school. you should try to figure things out yourself in order to learn. if not, use something better to change things with like sed.

Comment: Same question by same user (different account) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042196/replacing-a-word-in-a-file-using-c

Comment: I THING U PEOPLE NOT GETTING ME. I AM ASKING HOW TO APPEND WORDS IN BETWEEN SOME WHERE IN THE FILE.. THANKS

Comment: for eg i the file i have " i go to market" how to make it           "i go super market" want to insert super in between thanks

Answer (score 0):

- take all data with io function
- store it in double pointer ( use two dimension )
- after seeing EOF, clear the used file, close it
- write some function to do your task and manipulate the data stored in two dimension
- open it again, but now to write the manipulated data in it

Comment: i didnt get u can you please explain it little bit more thanks

Comment: If you want code, I can not give you any

Comment: no no i dont want code just  alittle more description